# Ocaml not able to find Labltk

Tags: window, ocaml

I am working on Debian Stable and have installed ocaml and opam from Debian repositories. I am trying following code from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Simple_windowed_application#OCaml):

```
#directory "+labltk"
#load "labltk.cma"

let () =
  let top = Tk.openTk() in
  Wm.title_set top "Tk-OCaml Example";
  let label = Label.create ~text:"There have been no clicks yet" top in
  let b =
    Button.create
        ~text:"click me"
        ~command:(fun () -> Tk.closeTk (); exit 0)
        top
  in
  Tk.pack [Tk.coe label; Tk.coe b];
  Tk.mainLoop ();
;;
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
$ ocaml simplewin.ml
Cannot find file labltk.cma.
File "simplewin.ml", line 5, characters 12-21:
Error: Unbound module Tk
```

I have `labltk` module installed:

```
$ opam list labltk
# Available packages for system:
labltk  8.06.0  OCaml interface to Tcl/Tk, including OCaml library explorer OCamlBrowser
```

Where is the problem and how can this be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: "...Programs that use the labltk library must be linked as follows: `ocamlc <other options> -I +labltk labltk.cma <other files>`..." (source https://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/ocaml/htmlman/manual042.html)

Comment: This does not work: `Error: Unbound module Tk` . Should I specify directory with this package? Where are these packages located?

Answer (score 0):

Labltk is no longer distributed along the compiler since OCaml 4.02. Consequently,

```
#directory "+labltk";;
#load "labltk.cma";;
```

is not the right command: you should use

```
#require "labltk";;
```

EDIT: The following code works for me:

```
#require "labltk";;                                                
let () =
  let top = Tk.openTk() in
  Wm.title_set top "Tk-OCaml Example";
  let label =
    Label.create ~text:"There have been no clicks yet" top in
  let b =
    Button.create
        ~text:"click me"
        ~command:(fun () -> Tk.closeTk (); exit 0)
        top
  in
  Tk.pack [Tk.coe label; Tk.coe b];
  Tk.mainLoop ();
;;
```

Comment: `#require "labltk";;` is not working: `syntax error` at `characters 0-1`

Comment: What was the context of this error? #require is a REPL directive, it cannot work outside of the REPL.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question above that I am running a source file on command line as: `$ ocaml simplewin.ml`

Comment: Then you have a syntax error earlier in your `simplewin.ml` file (in other words, your code amended with `#require...` works fine for me) . Could you please edit your question to show its current contents?

Comment: Maybe its a version problem. Version for my ocaml is 4.02.3 and for opam is 1.2.2 .